# How to use Ui Component in frontend magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

In Magento 2 i want create grid in frontend, but i don't how do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-list-with-pager-in-frontend/

Answer (score 3):

Check this articles, I found them very simple and clear.

- https://belvg.com/blog/ui-grid-component-on-the-front-end-in-magento-2.html
- http://magefoo.com/building-an-admin-grid-in-the-front-end-of-magento-2/